# Overwriting a C system after exec?

Tags: c, linux

So I used wrap to override the malloc call in my program, I didn't think that if I exec'd another it would work, and it didn't. I figure this is because it wasn't linked with my program. How could I overwrite a C call in another program?
Sample:

```
void* __wrap_malloc(size_t size) {
    void* mal = __real_malloc(size);
    printf("malloced %i @ %i\n", size, mal);
    return mal;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    malloc(1024);
    execl("/bin/bash", "/bin/bash", (char *) NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like off-topic, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an environment variable LD_PRELOAD to point to a shared library overriding required functions.

See http://hackerboss.com/overriding-system-functions-for-fun-and-profit/